# Stream .mp4 file from CentOS server via php

Tags: php, apache, upload, centos

I have a few videos i want to stream on my website and for that i want to rent my own VPS / Dedicated server.

Because my videos will be about 20/30 min long / 300MB each i want to be prepared for a lot of views/traffic.

I think the best thing i could do is rent a VPS and maybe later on a dedicated server to ensure fast speeds and no problem handling all my traffic. Though i am not sure how to set this up.

I got my website running via a host. On my website users can watch the videos. Of course i can't just put them on my web host so that's where the vps / dedicated comes into play.

I don't have any experience with VPS other than a windows VPS / Directadmin pre-installed.

Now i want to know what the best set-up should be so that i can:

1. Upload my video files to the VPS

   2. Stream the videos on my (php) website.

The website is done already with a nice HTML 5 player. If i enter the source a.k.a. link to the video it will play the video as it should.

So that brings me to the question. Can i upload .mp4 files to a CentOS server and let PHP stream those files ( so this would be 2 seperate servers )? And if yes, how would i be able to do that? Does a VPS also have some kind of IP address with mapping or something? Or should i install php / apache on the VPS to access the files?

Or should i host my website on the same server as the videos? In that case i could simply install directadmin and upload the website/files to it. Right? Yet i would like to keep those 2 seperated.

I would really love some advice!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have no Idea how much traffic you're expecting and want to save yourself some hassle then I'd go with a cloud based solution. Also, PHP has nothing to do with streaming the video to the client in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php stream ?! it's not correct. You don't neet use php to send your video stream. And you can play videos hosting on different server without problems.

You must use dedicated server + nginx (not apache because apache isn't very good to send file/video stream)

My advice is:

- Centos 7 on dedicated server
- Nginx
- Set on your player direct link of your video.

  example:

  ```
     <video width="1028" height="720" controls><source src="http://fileServerDomain.com/path/video/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">  </video>
  ```

Comment: Yes it's very hard to explain what i mean if i'm not sure what i'm talking about ;). So if i am correct i can get a Centos 7 dedicated server, install Nginx and than access the server with a FTP client or so?

Comment: Sure, you can access to your server using ftp. You should configure your server with an ftp server as vsftpd or profptd. (or you can try to upload files with sftp using client ftp as filezilla) You can upload your files with ftp and send them to your users with nginx/html5 player

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try this once everything is ready to go. I was looking for something like Nginx but as i am new to this kind of pie i don't know what i was looking for.